# Bash: Parse multi-line into single-line commands

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have to write a Bash script which checks if another Bash script contains a certain command line. Since Bash allows you to split a command line over multiple lines, my script must be able to merge the corresponding lines before the actual pattern matching can take place.

**How do I parse all multi-line into single-line commands in a Bash script?**

*Example*

I want to check if a certain script contains the *ls* command - and if it contains the *ls* command, I want to know which parameters are passed to the *ls* command. To answer this question, I could use *sed*. But therefore I have to merge all multi-line commands first.

Input:

```
# My comment \
ls \
-a \
-l
```

Output:

```
# My comment \
ls -a -l
```

Example for an invalid output:

```
# My comment ls -a -l
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just before shellshock, I [answered a question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25293910/1566221) about eliminating comments in bash scripts. My answer used the simple trick of creating a function by enclosing the contents of the script file inside `tmp_() { ... }`, and then using `declare -f tmp_` to pretty-print the function. In the pretty-printed output, there are no comments and lines continued with a backslash-newline have been resolved to single lines. (Except inside backticked command substitution.)

Some other reformatting is also done. For example, compound commands are split into several lines. And some forms of line continuation are not reformatted; for example, a line ending with a pipe symbol is not altered. But it should satisfy the use-case in this question. (See example output below.)

Of course, the function definition needs to be evaluated, which means that the script being pretty-printed might include an injection attack. In the code I suggested, the function definition is evaluated by way of the bash feature which allows functions to be exported and shared with a child process. At the time I wrote this little hack, I believed that mechanism to be safer than calling `eval`, but as it turns out I was wrong.

Since shellshock, there have been a number of improvements to the code bash uses to import function definitions, closing the door on at least some injection attacks, but there is clearly no assurance that the procedure is completely safe.

If you are going to run the script being analyzed, then using this procedure to pretty-print it probably does not increase your vulnerability; an attacker could simply insert the dangerous code directly in the script and there would be no need to jump through hoops to hide the attack in a way which might bypass the safety checks in the function import code.

All the same, you should think carefully about security issues, both with this little program and with whatever plans you might have to execute arbitrary scripts.

Here is the version of the pretty-printer which works with a post-shellshock-patched bash (and will not work with previous bash versions):

```
env "BASH_FUNC_tmp_%%=() {
$(<script_name)
}" bash -c 'declare -f tmp_' | tail -n+2
```

Substitute the name of the file containing the script for `script_name`, in the second line. You might want to adjust the `tail` command; it removes the wrapper function name, but does not remove the braces which surround the script body.

The original version, which will work on pre-shellshock versions of bash, can be found in the referenced SO answer.

---

#### Sample.

Tested against the input provided by [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228598/24557):

```
{ 
    echo \\;
    echo a#b;
    echo 'foo\
bar';
    cat  <<EOF
thisis joined
this 'aswell'
$(ls -l)
EOF

    cat  <<'EOF'
this is\
not joined
EOF

    echo "$(ls -l)";
    echo `ls \\
-l`
}
```

This differs from Stéphane's suggested output:

- Lines have been indented, and many have been terminated with semicolons. Whitespace has been added and/or deleted in many lines.
- `cat << E\OF` has been changed to `cat <<'EOF'`, which is semantically identical.
- The nested continuation line in the backticked command substitution at the end has not been modified. (The continuation line in the `$(...)` command substituion is eliminated.)

Comment: Looks like you were very close to discovering shellshock then.

Answer (score 2):

This works in more cases, now; see if it does what you're expecting:

```
sed ':loop /^[^#].*[^\\]\\$/N; s/\\\n//; t loop' input
```

It prints every line by default; if it finds a backslash (escaped because it's a special character) at the end of a line ($) -- and there is not a hash mark at the beginning of the line, then join it with the next line (N) modified by searching & replacing the backslash (escaped again) and newline character with *nothing*. If the search & replace did something, then go back to the "loop" tag and re-run the search.

Input:

```
# My comment \
ls \
-al

# leading comment
echo some \
long \
text
# trailing comment

ls -al
```

Output:

```
# My comment \
ls -al

# leading comment
echo some long text
# trailing comment

ls -al
```

Comment: This solution also merges comments. **Example**: It merges the lines "# My comment \" and "ls -al" into a single line "# My comment ls -al". Moreover, it doesn't work if you have a command which consists of more than two lines.

Comment: I've updated the answer to take into account commented-and-backslashed lines as well as multi-lines.

Comment: I added [^\\\] for the double-backslash case; @StéphaneChazelas has pointed out some good cases. The rabbit-hole is too deep for me with here-docs and quoted strings.

Comment: I've just upvoted your answer as it fullfills my requirements. I will accept this answer if nobody else provides a solution which also covers the cases which Stéphane Chazelas has pointed out.

Comment: In case no one finds a general solution, you could work around the shortcomings of my approach by grepping for "<<" and " ' " and ' " ' (single and double quote marks) as places to manually inspect.

Comment: Thank you, found useful for mkimage-profiles' make target tracer based on John Graham-Cumming's approach: http://www.cmcrossroads.com/ask-mr-make/6535-tracing-rule-execution-in-gnu-make (the target/prerequisite lines lacking subsequent recipe don't invoke shell and thus avoid tracing).

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer, just a note on the things to consider for a solution to work in the general case.

```
#! /bin/sh -
echo \\
echo a#\
b
echo 'foo\
bar'
cat << EOF
this\
is joined
this 'as\
well'
$(ls \
-l)
EOF
cat << E\OF
this is\
not joined
EOF
echo "$(ls \
-l)"
echo `ls \\
-l`
```

My understanding of the intent of the question would be that it should be transformed to:

```
#! /bin/sh -
echo \\
echo a#b
echo 'foo\
bar'
cat << EOF
thisis joined
this 'aswell'
$(ls -l)
EOF
cat << E\OF
this is\
not joined
EOF
echo "$(ls -l)"
echo `ls -l`
```

Answer (score 0):

The history converts typical multi line commands into a single line. Just type things in and then issue a "cursor up" to see the conversion.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a totally different topic. I know that my English isn't perfect, so if there is something unclear, just ask.

Comment: I recommend you to try my proposal, it does apply to your question...

Comment: While this would work in an interactive shell, I think the confusion stems from the question asking about making changes to a script file on disk -- not requiring the commands to be entered interactively (and thus into the shell history).

Answer (score 0):

To replace newlines by spaces, you can just

```
tr '\n' ' '
```

This can leave some backslashes in the code, so you should probably rather replace newlines preceded by backslash by spaces

```
 perl -pe 's/\\\n/ /'
```

This can still go wrong (HERE documents, comments, etc.), but to get it 100% correct, you'd have to write a full shell parser.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it also merges lines which are commented.

Comment: @Lugaxx: It mentions the problem, and also mentions the solution: writing a full shell parser. But do you really need to catch 100% of the matches? Can't you just overgenerate a bit and then process the resulting list manually?

Comment: Replacing newline by a space definitely does not work. In most cases, a semicolon works.

Comment: @schily: For a single multiline command (check the example above), semicolon wouldn't work.