# quick and easy way to comment out multi lined print statements

Tags: shell-script, scripting

Is there a quick and easy way to comment out multi lined print statements? something like this?

```
                printf("3387 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s \n", 
                strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
```

I mainly have three types, with a sporadic fourth one.

```
            printf("3402 checking return stuff \n");
            printf("3408 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s \n", 
            strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
            printf("3410 function_type_for_proper_return %s \n", function_type_for_proper_return);
```

Here is my sporadic fourth one. The `%c` is sometimes useful in figuring out why an if statement or while loop is not behaving as expected.

```
        printf("2340 symbol_table_variables[i][1] is %s.\n", symbol_table_variables[i][1]);
        printf("2341 symbol_table_variables[i][2] is %c.\n", symbol_table_variables[i][2][0]);
```

One more complication please :). Is it possible to leave these two types of print statements alone?

```
        printf("2434 REJECT\n");
        printf("2534 ACCEPT\n");
```

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/228547/117549

Comment: what language are you attempting to parse? What scripting tools to you wish to use?

Comment: @glennjackman Its a c program. I will use any tools that will do the job :). Will awk, perl, or sed do the job?

Comment: You have multi-line statements; do you ever have multi-statement lines (for example, `printf("hello\n"); i++;`)?  Do you ever (might you ever) have a semicolon in a string (for example, `printf("I came; I saw; I conquered.\n");`)?

Comment: @G-Man I honestly didn't know the first one is legal :D. When is that one useful? No to the semicolon in a string. I have three main types with a sporadic fourth that I want to comment out. I also have  two types of print statements I want to leave alone.

Comment: The only reason to put multiple statements on one line would be if you had a need to reduce your line count; i.e., no real reason.  As you might imagine, it's considered to be bad form, which might be tolerable for very short statements like `i=0; j=1;` or `i++; j++;`; so the example I gave is an example of something that you shouldn't do.  So just forget I mentioned it.    :-)    ⁠

Comment: Why did I get downvoted?

Comment: I didn’t downvote you, but I can guess at some reasons: (1) Your question is meandering: long and unfocused.  (2) It has four code blocks, with the last nine lines of the first one being *repeated* as the second one (except indented differently).  (3) The fact that three of the code blocks have lines so long that they need to be scrolled horizontally makes the question harder to read, and is totally unnecessary.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) You say “I mainly have three types [of print statements], with a sporadic fourth one.” but you don’t identify those four types of print statements in any clear way that I can perceive.  You show ten *examples* of print statements (not counting the four that are duplicated, or the last two), and you leave it to the reader to figure out what patterns you’re thinking of that characterize/distinguish the four types.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) The explanation of why you use `%c` is unclear, unhelpful (it doesn’t illuminate, illustrate, or explain anything), and irrelevant.  (6) And then, after talking about the four types of print statements (three plus the “sporadic fourth one”), you spring two more on us.  (7) Just as a matter of logic, it doesn’t make sense to say “Handle types 1, 2, 3, and 4 in a special way, and leave types 5 and 6 alone.”  I mean, specifying two different lists.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  What are we supposed to do with a print statement that doesn’t match one of the six types (whatever they are)?  You should specify one group to handle one way, and say that everything else is handled the other way.  (8) You give us four code blocks of *input* and never *show* what you want the output to look like.  (9) You correctly indent the multi-line `get_function_type_for_proper_return` function call statement, but you don’t properly indent the multi-line `printf` statements, making the code hard to read.

Comment: @cokedude: Hello.  I answered your question over a week ago.  Do you care?

Comment: @G-Man I'm sorry. I will work on fixing it. Thank you.

Comment: @cokedude: Hey.  I answered your question over 100 days ago.  Do you care?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t make sense to say
“Handle the members of *this* group one way,
and handle the members of *this other group* this other way.” 
You should specify one group to handle one way,
and say that everything else is handled the other way. 
So I’m going to assume that
you want *all* `printf` statements commented out
except for ones that look like one of the following:

```
        printf("2434 REJECT\n");
        printf("2534 ACCEPT\n");
```

So here’s a “simple” solution to do that:

```
awk '
        /printf/        { comment=1 }
        /printf\("[0-9]* REJECT/    { comment=0 }
        /printf\("[0-9]* ACCEPT/    { comment=0 }
                        { if (comment) printf "//"
                          print }
        /;/             { comment=0 }
'
```

Here’s what it does:

- Whenever it sees a line that contains `printf`,
  it sets the `comment` flag. 
  (Note that this will match calls to `fprintf` and `sprintf`. 
  It will also match *comments* and *strings* containing the word `printf`;
  e.g.,

  ```
          /* This printf is used for figuring out what an if statement is doing. */
  ```

  Adjust it if you need it to be more specific.)
- Then, if it turns out that it is a `printf` of a string of digits,
  followed by a space, followed by `REJECT` or `ACCEPT`,
  it turns *off* the `comment` flag,
  because you don’t want those statements commented out. 
  Note that these regexs are somewhat broad —
  they will accept *any number* of digits (not just four),
  and they don’t check that the word is the last thing on the line. 
  Adjust these if you need them to be more specific.
- Then it executes a two-line block of code for every line of input:

  - If the `comment` flag is set,
    it writes out `//`, to comment out the line. 
    Note that in `awk`, as in C,
    `printf` does not automatically write a newline.
  - Then, for every line, it writes the line. 
    (In `awk`, the `print` statement *does* automatically
    write a newline at the end;
    and the default is to write the input line to the output.) 
    So this writes the input line to the output,
    commented out with `//` if it is (part of) a `printf` statement
    (and not one of the special cases).
- Then, if it sees a semicolon, it turns off the `comment` flag. 
  This allows the `comment` flag to stay set
  while a multi-line `printf` statement is processed. 
  And this is why it’s important that your `printf` strings
  never include a semicolon,
  because this `awk` script would mistake that for the end of the statement.

For example, for the input

```
    cmp_str9 = strcmp("return", strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
    printf("4006 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
    printf("4007 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n",
        strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
    if (cmp_str9 == 0)
    {
        printf("2534 ACCEPT\n");
        printf("3402 checking return stuff\n");
        return_match_flag = 1;
    }
```

yields this output

```
    cmp_str9 = strcmp("return", strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
//    printf("4006 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
//    printf("4007 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n",
//        strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
    if (cmp_str9 == 0)
    {
        printf("2534 ACCEPT\n");
//        printf("3402 checking return stuff\n");
        return_match_flag = 1;
    }
```

---

You didn’t describe the output that you want precisely. 
Putting `//` at the beginning of each line
is an easy way to comment out code. 
You might prefer to put `/*` before the first line
and `*/` after the last one. 
I advise against doing this in an automated script,
because any `/*…*/` style comment in the commented-out code
would end the comment (because `/*…*/` style comments do not nest). 
Of course you could *look for* `*/` in the commented-out code,
but that gets messy.

But there’s another way to comment-out blocks of C code. 
Anything between a

```
#if 0
```

and an

```
#endif
```

essentially disappears from the source code file,
as far as the compiler is concerned. 
While this will blow up if it *overlaps*
with any other pre-processor (`#…`) blocks, it does nest nicely. 
We could write `#if 0` before *every* `printf` statement,
and `#endif` after,
but I thought it would be nicer to detect blocks of print statements. 
So I came up with this:

```
awk '
        /printf/        { starting_comment=1 }
        /printf\("[0-9]* REJECT/    { starting_comment=0 }
        /printf\("[0-9]* ACCEPT/    { starting_comment=0 }
                        { if (starting_comment) {
                                starting_comment=0
                                if (in_a_comment==0) print "#if 0"
                                in_a_comment=1
                          }
                          if (in_a_comment==2) {
                                print "#endif"
                                in_a_comment=0
                          }
                          print
                        }
        /;/             { if (in_a_comment==1) {
                                in_a_comment=2
                          }
                        }
        END             {
                          if (in_a_comment==2) {
                                print "#endif"
                                in_a_comment=0
                          }
                        }
'
```

You probably don’t really need the `END` block; it comes into play
only if the last line in the input is a `printf` statement. 
Of course the last line in a C source code file should always be `}`.

For the example input shown above, this produces

```
    cmp_str9 = strcmp("return", strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
#if 0
    printf("4006 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
    printf("4007 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n",
        strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
#endif
    if (cmp_str9 == 0)
    {
        printf("2534 ACCEPT\n");
#if 0
        printf("3402 checking return stuff\n");
#endif
        return_match_flag = 1;
    }
```

Note how the first two `printf` statements are combined into a single block.