# How to compose a list of all the executables that are used in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Executables as a general term for:

- common binaries
- scripts

I suppose it can be done with some fat regex, matching start of new lines, conjunctions like `&&` and `||`, inline after `;` etc...but I was wondering is there a simpler way?

Comment: How do you define 'executables'?

Comment: anything called outside of the script, so other scripts and binaries pretty much, regex alone can't handle aliases though but let's be sane and compromise on just binaries and other scripts/wrappers

Comment: You'd probably have to write a parser that understands bash.  For example, using regex etc, the line `echo cat` would pick up `cat` as an executable, when in fact you wouldn't want that to happen.

Comment: Parsing a shell script is tricky to do right. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/228547/117549

Comment: You could just use `strace -f`, assuming of course you don't mind running the script....

Comment: @garethTheRed It wouldn't given the proper rules, you would treat anything after echo as a string, unless preceded by `\`` or `$(.*` etc, it just get quite complex

Comment: @Wildcard that does not take into consideration any conditional, so it is a no-no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be happy enough just collating the "words", then pass them through the ``which` command. Perhaps like the following:

```
cat $SCRIPT | tr -c '[[:alnum:]-_]' '\\n' | sort -u | xargs which
```

The word collation in the `tr` phrase excludes the more "esoteric" commands like `[` and such. That's where you might need to experiment unless you're just looking for "ordinary" command words. The above of course also finds command words that perhaps are not used as such in the script, and to make that distinction you'll indeed need more of a parser. And you might as well want an initial `sed 's/#.*//` rather than `cat` to exclude the comments in the script (although that fails to pass where `#` is included in strings).

Comment: this requires all the execs to be available.

Comment: Indeed. That kind of was the question, wasn't it. If you rather want a list of expected but missing executables it's a notch trickier. But you might end it with `xargs -I + zsh -c "which +"` instead, using the `which` command of `zsh` to gain "not found" notes for all words that are not found as executables.